# Subset of vectors which removed from the set does not change the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose I have a set of vectors $V$ in a vector space and $S$ is a subset of $V$ such that $\dim(V-S) = \dim(V)$. From this what can we deduce about the structure of $S$?
I think the elements of $S$ must not all reside on the same hyperplane? Am I correct???

Comment: $\mathrm{dim}$ is a property of vector space. In particular it is a property for vector subspaces. Then there is no sense  $\mathrm{dim}(V-S)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me rephrase the question. If dim(span(V-S)) = dim(span(V)), can one tell that the elements of S must not all reside on the same hyperplane. Moreover, can one also say that the basis of span(V-S) is also a basis of span(V) itself and vice versa?

Comment: There isn't a lot one can say about such $S$. It can be as large as the complement of a basis, that is (supposing $V$ is a finite dimensional space) all vectors except a finite number. In particular $S$ does not have to be contained in a hyperplane.

Comment: @SudiptaRoy When rephrasing a question, it is customary to *actually* rephrase the question (i.e. edit the question), not just add more comments.  This makes the question easier to search for and more useful to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your edit: You want $\dim(span(V-S)) = \dim(V)$ for, say, $\dim(V) < \infty$.

Then $span(V-S)$ is a vector subspace of $V$, and thus having dimension equal to $\dim(V)$ is equivalent to $span(V-S) = V$.

So yes, any basis of $V-S$ is a basis of $V$, and their basis vectors can be taken from $V-S$, otherwise it would be no generating set of $span(V-S)$.

So all we need is that $V-S$ is no proper subspace of $V$, which means that $S$ can be like the whole complement of a subspace **minus** one point outside that subspace. Those subsets can be huge, and don't have to be contained in any hyperplane.

Develop your intuition on the situation $V = \mathbb R^2$. Then the set $S = \{ (x,y) : x \neq 0 \}$ has for complement the $y$-axis, so dimension dropped. But take $S - \{(1,0)\}$, we have the complement $y$-axis $\cup \{(1,0)\}$ which has as a span all of $\mathbb R^2$!

---

Even worse: Take some basis $B = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and let $S = V-B$. Then of course $span(V-S) = V$. Your subsets $S$ can really be as big is the complement of $\dim(V)$ points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This means the for all subset Y of S, dim(V-Y) =dim(V)

Answer (score 1):

As I said you in the comments, $\mathrm{dim}(S^c)$ has sense iff $S^c$ is a subspace of $V$. But if $\mathrm{dim}(S^c)=\mathrm{dim}(V)$, then $S^c=V$ (cause the only subspace of $V$ with the same dimension is $V$ itself). Thus $S=\emptyset$.

**Edit** I'm supposing $\mathrm{dim}V<\infty$

Comment: Is this true also if $V$ is a vector space of uncountable infinite dimension? I'm not sure...